# are there any adjustments I can make to speed this up?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, speed

I am getting speeds as low as 56 kbps down to 2kbps. is there any way I can speed this up? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try getting a new circuit. The one you were on may be bad. Try restarting Tor browser to clean out your circuits

However, you **will** see slower speeds because of the way the Tor network works:

In short, you are routed through three 'relays': a guard (first hop), a middle relay, and an 'exit'(last hop). That itself will slow the connection down. On top of that, your traffic is encrypted multiple times, and each relay has to decrypt some to find out the next relay. That takes time, and if you're unfortunate enough to get a slow relay, it's even worse.

Privacy has a price, and sometimes it is speed of the web

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using an Ethernet cable which would make the internet speed much better, smoother and more constant.

Also try accessing that website (without tor) : http://archive1.parrotsec.org/ and navigate where it says sppedtest. Then on the URL find and replace the results.html part and hit enter.

That would let you know what your maximum upload and download speeds are and how much of the traffic you receive / send is junk.

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease the number of hops tor is using. But that is highly not recommended!
You can change your entry node (guard node). This is not recommended either...